# dynamic menu and submenu by clicking menu the submenu should be displayed,my id not firing in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, navigation

```
global.php
return array(
     'navigation' => array(
         'default' => array(
           array(             


     'label' =>'Home',
                'route'    => 'home',
             'use_route_match' => true,

           ),
           array(
                'label'=>'Access',
                'route'    => 'access',
              'constraints' => 
      array (

        'class' => 'access',
      ),

               'use_route_match' => true,

    'pages' => array(                   
         'city'=>  array(
             'label'=>'City',
                'route'    => 'city',
              'id' => 'city',
             'use_route_match' => true,
             ),       
           ),
           ),
                  array(
               'label'=>'Privacy', 
                'route'    => 'privacy',
            'use_route_match' => true,

 ),
     ),
     ),
```

);

Comment: if I add the comment 'visible'=>false in city sublist hidden but when I m clicking access I need to display..will anyone clear my issue

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){$('li #menu-access').hover(function() { 
 $('li #menu-city').show(); }), $('li #menu-privacy').hover(function() { $('li #menu-city').hide(); }) });

Comment: finally,i got the output!!!!